# How do I select specific tags from a data set?

Tags: javascript, html, button, tags, dataset

I'm doing a project for uni and I'm a bit of a coding noob. I'm wanting to have 3 buttons on a page, which all connect to one js dataset. I want each button to only show specific information from the data. For example - the data references different businesses in Melbourne that provide printing services. I want each button to be a different service i.e general printing, binding, photography. Can someone please help this poor soul? ps: sorry if my technical language is terrible.
This is what I currently have;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
    populateData();
    }

    function populateData(){
    var table = document.getElementById("DATA");//get <table>
    table.innerHTML = ""//make blank
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>URL</th></tr>";//add table headers

    for(i = 0; i < plData.length; i++){

        var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");//make <tr>


        tableRow.className = plData[i].plTags("printing");//apply printer linker category as class name

        tableRow.innerHTML += "<td>" +  plData[i].plName + "</td><td>"+ plData[i].plStreet + " " + plData[i].plCity + " " + plData[i].plRegion + " " + plData[i].plPostcode + "</td><td><a href='" + plData[i].plHyperlink + "'>" + plData[i].plHyperlink + "</a></td>";//add HTML to <tr>
        table.appendChild(tableRow);
    }

}
```

Comment: This site is limited to getting help on existing code, not on getting someone else to write code for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just edited the question :)

Comment: Please provide the sample data set and any HTML you already have.